how to find regional overlap between two dfs
I have one df that has chr and position and the other has chr, start, end. I want to find all of the regions from df1 that match the chr and overlap with the position of df0. Please see the example below for more clarity. FYI I have large dfs
df0:

chr     position 
1         33
1         100
1         400 


df1:  
chr      start        end      label
1         30          40       dog
1         90          110      dog
1         85          200      cat


this is what I want:
final_df:  

chr     position   matched_start    matched_end    label
1         33             30          40            dog
1         100            90          110           dog
1         100            85          200           cat



You can use first merge your dfs on chr and then apply your matching logic on the merged dataframe. You can try the following:
import pandas as pd

# Example dataframes
df0 = pd.DataFrame({'chr': [1, 1, 1], 'position': [33, 100, 400]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'chr': [1, 1, 1], 'start': [30, 90, 85], 'end': [40, 110, 200], 'label': ['dog', 'dog', 'cat']})

# Create a helper function to check for overlap
def find_overlap(pos, start, end):
    if pos >= start and pos <= end:
        return start, end
    return pd.Series([pd.NA, pd.NA])

# Merge the dataframes on 'chr'
merged_df = pd.merge(df0, df1, on='chr', how='outer')

# Apply the helper function to each row and create new columns
merged_df[['matched_start', 'matched_end']] = merged_df.apply(lambda row: find_overlap(row['position'], row['start'], row['end']), axis=1, result_type='expand')

# Drop rows with NaN values in the new columns
final_df = merged_df.dropna(subset=['matched_start', 'matched_end'])

# Reorder and rename columns
final_df = final_df[['chr', 'position', 'matched_start', 'matched_end', 'label']]

# Reset index
final_df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

print(final_df)

The output of the above code is as follows:
   chr  position matched_start matched_end label
0    1        33            30          40   dog
1    1       100            90         110   dog
2    1       100            85         200   cat

